# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I recently installed anaconda on my notebook. When I try to open jupyter notebook, the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ismael\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'
```

[image: conda error]

I've tried uninstalling acaconda and reinstalling it, but the error is still there.

I have the following configurations:

Win 11
Anaconda 2.5.0
Python 3.11.5
[image: python]

[image: Environment variables]

I believe that jupyter notebook should appear in this list, but I tried to install it with pip install notebook at the anaconda prompt, and it still doesn't appear.

[image: conda prompt]

I've already tried reinstalling anaconda. I hope it will open after the fix.

Comment: See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/not-able-to-open-jupyter-using-anaconda-navigator-or-normally/22998/4?u=fomightez) and try running `python -m notebook` in the Anaconda power shell. See the earlier posts in the thread for links to other similar posts that have may have other things to try if that isn't the solution.

Comment: It worked, even in windows cmd. Thank you very much. Do you know how to fix it so that it opens through anaconda navigator?

Comment: No, I haven't dug into what people are saying surrounding it yet to tell what the issue is. I'm not a Windows user. I suspect it is either permissions or just something not getting connected when installing Anaconda/conda or something getting broken by old files being around when updating Anaconda/conda.